# Keras: input shape of a dense layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am reading the tutorial at:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/generative-adversarial-networks

Where there is a network called `generator` with the following architecture:

```
generator = Sequential()

generator.add(Dense(256, input_dim=64, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

generator.add(Dense(512))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

generator.add(Dense(1024))
generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

# last layer output a 28x28 image
generator.add(Dense(784, activation='tanh'))
generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

The input of the generator is called noise like below:

```
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, input_dim])
print (noise.shape)
```

The shape of noise is:

```
noise shape:  (128, 64)
```

So we have:

```
generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
```

Here is what confuses me: the `input_dim` of the generator is already specified as 64 in the first Dense layer, why is it allowed to input noise with the shape (128,64)?

I understand the idea is to compute 128 elements in a batch each time. My question is what exactly the function `predict` can take? The Keras document (https://keras.io/models/sequential/) has the following:

```
predict(x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)

x: The input data, as a Numpy array (or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple inputs).
```

But how do we know which dimension in x should be `batch_size` and which dimension in x should be `input_dim`? What happen if the `noise shape = (64,128)` ? or `(64, 256, 256)` or `(256, 256, 64)`? which ones are allowed? Is there a hidden document somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keras models expect the first dimension of your data to be the batch dimension. You can have a look at the docs on the [Input layers](https://keras.io/layers/core/#input) from the functional API. This layer has a `shape` argument as well as an `batch_shape` argument. Both work, but the latters allow to explicitly define a batch shape.

To answer your questions:

- `noise shape = (64,128)` would give an error because the expected input dim is 64 and you provide 128 (the 64 in the first dimension does not matter here as the batch size can be anything and does not change the model architecture)
- `(64, 256, 256)` and `(256, 256, 64)` would give you an error because an input with two dimensions (+ 1 batch dimension) is provided, where the model expects 1-dimensional input (+ 1 batch dimension).

Also check out the docs of the [Sequential](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) API:

> Pass an input_shape argument to the first layer. This is a shape tuple
>   (a tuple of integers or None entries, where None indicates that any
>   positive integer may be expected). In input_shape, the batch dimension
>   is not included.
>
> If you ever need to specify a fixed batch size for your inputs (this
>   is useful for stateful recurrent networks), you can pass a  batch_size
>   argument to a layer. If you pass both batch_size=32 and
>   input_shape=(6, 8) to a layer, it will then expect every batch of
>   inputs to have the batch shape (32, 6, 8).

Comment: Thanks! ... I am still confused, I thought the above code is using Sequential API rather than functional API. If using Sequential API, doesn't it say "In input_shape, the batch dimension is not included."? What did I miss here?

Comment: Also, where in the document say "Keras models expect the first dimension of your data to be the batch dimension. "? I couldn't find it ... Thanks!

Comment: Your code makes indeed use of the Sequential API, but the idea is the same. I'm not sure if you'll find that quote somewhere literally in the docs.

Comment: Thanks sdcbr! So the maximum dim for input_shape is 2, it can be (input_dim_1, input_dim_2 ) or (batch_dim, input_dim)? Though not explicitly specify in the docs. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: In the Sequential API, `input_shape` never expects a batch size. If you want to, you can specify a batch size through the additional `batch_size` argument. Same idea for the functional API: `shape` never expects a batch shape, `batch_shape` does.

Comment: mmm ... then in the code: generated_images = generator.predict(noise) , which argument is corresponding to "noise" here? nothing in the document seems to match this scenario, but yet the code in this tutorial is working ...why?

Comment: Noise is of shape `(128, 64)`, which means 128 examples, each consisting of 64 inputs. `model.predict()` actually has an argument `batch_size`, which defaults to 32. When calling `predict()`, the model will pass over your data in 4 batches of size `(32, 64)`. The number of examples does not matter. You could have passed an array of shape `(500, 64)` and it would still have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about input data and batch size.

- Input data contain many data samples, each sample is a row in the input matrix. Number of samples is input size.
- Batch is a subset of input data that is computed in a pass. Number of samples in a batch in batch size.

In your example, 128 is input size. If you do not specify batch size, it will compute all input data at a time, thus input data is equivalent to a batch (e.g., train/predict on an online data generator). You can also specify batch size to divide the input data and compute on smaller batches.